# How to click on a hidden element in a coded UI test?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I created a coded UI test of a very long form.  One of the form elements is actually a javascript widget that uses jQuery and bootstrap to alter the value of a hidden form value. (Essentially I'm mimicing an optgroup that has three levels).

The test records just fine, however when I replay the test it gets to the javascript widget and throws the error

```
Cannot perform 'Click'on the hidden control.  Additional Details:
TechnologyNmae: 'Web'
ControlType: 'HyperLink'
TagName: 'A'
ID: ''
Name: ''
Target: ''
InnerText: 'Atlanta'
```

How can I get the test browser to click the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

Create a different method and assertion for the inner text of the control rather than for a complete control. In my case problem occurred "**Cannot perform 'Click'on the hidden control.**" while uploading a file using a button. So i changed my assertion by focusing the assertion to the inner text rather than the control. It worked in my case.

here is the code generated after creating the assertion:

```
public void AssertBrowser()
        {
            #region Variable Declarations
            WinEdit uIItemEdit = this.UIMozillaFirefoxWindow.UIItemCell.UIItemEdit;
            #endregion

            // Verify that the 'Name' property of '...' text box equals '...'
            Assert.AreEqual(this.AssertBrowserExpectedValues.UIItemEditName, uIItemEdit.Name);
        }
```